# Fullcalendar doesn't load CSS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3, laravel-9

I'm implementing fullcalendar in my project that has Laravel 9 and Vue 3.

I think it is not loading the css as the on-screen calendar is looking like this: [Calendar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hizsE.jpg).

I have already made several settings. Even the Vue part is working because the calendar is working.

Below in the images are the settings that are today.

```
package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite --host",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
        "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.11.2",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.1.2",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.9.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.41",
        "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5"
    }
}

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

import fs from 'fs';

const host = 'site.com.br'; 

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    server: {
        host,
        hmr: { host },
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync('C:\\laragon\\etc\\ssl\\privada25296.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('C:\\laragon\\etc\\ssl\\certificado25296.crt'),
        },
    },
});

index.vue

<script>
import { useToast } from "vue-toastification";

import '@fullcalendar/core/vdom' // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import { INITIAL_EVENTS, createEventId } from './event-utils'

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
    },

    data() {
        return {
            calendarOptions: {
                plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin ],
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                initialEvents: INITIAL_EVENTS, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed

            }
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        const toast = useToast();

        this.loadUserCustomers();

        Echo.channel('agendamentos_database_user_customer_created')
            .listen('UserCustomerCreated', (e) => {
                toast.success('Novo cliente vinculado!')
           });
    },

    methods: {
        loadUserCustomers() {
            axios.get('/api/calendar')
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log( response.data.data );

                    //this.userCustomers = response.data
                })
                .catch(response => {
                    console.log('Erro')
                })
        }
    },
}
```

In the fullcalendar documentation, the following is mentioned about CSS.

> CSS: All of FullCalendar’s CSS will be automatically loaded as long as your build system is able to process .css file imports. See Initializing with an ES6 Build System for more information on configuring your build system. [https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue#:~:text=ticket%20%23152.-,CSS,-All%20of%20FullCalendar%E2%80%99s](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue#:%7E:text=ticket%20%23152.-,CSS,-All%20of%20FullCalendar%E2%80%99s)

When I access [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6) about ES6 Build System, it is described that I need to use webpack, and in the Laravel application, vite is used.

Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Comment: did you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include _relevant_ code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: Yes @Joseph, and it's normal.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is almost entirely a useless repetition of information that is already in the tags and should not be in the title at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is pretty meaningless if you remove the tags (which you should during your edit).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by loading allocate the size of the calendar
hope this solve your problem and I did it with the cdn

```js
calendar.render();
calendar.setOption('height', 700);
```